# Boostrap inline tabs on navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working a little exercise on codepen and trying to style the tabs of navbar using boostrap, but when I was using the original code on the site or adding

```
class="list-inline"
```

It ended up with the items on each line [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6dNd.png).

Can anyone explain why that happened? I am using boostrap 4 and here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
   </div>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would have to use list-inline-item class to the li item as well.

see the fiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/pr6t58wL/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code I think it is work on your requirement.

```
<div id="exTab1" class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#youridname1" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#youridname2" data-toggle="tab">Using nav-pills</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="youridname1">
      <h3>Content's background color is the same for the tab</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="youridname1">
      <h3>We use the class nav-pills instead of nav-tabs which automatically creates a background color for the tab</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your try on plunkr ?